# Passing a Truncated Vector by Reference

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to pass a truncated vector by reference so that it still changes the original vector.

Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to do.  I want the vector

`x = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }`

when the function exits.  When my code finishes, though, I get

`{ 1, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 }`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void example(vector<int> &x)
{
    vector<int>::iterator ii = x.begin();
    vector<int>::iterator jj = x.end();

    if (ii == jj) { return; }
    else { 
        *ii = 1;
        example(vector<int>(ii + 1, jj));
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> x = { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 };
    example(x);

    for (vector<int>::iterator ii = x.begin(); ii != x.end(); ii++)
        cout << *ii << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You could pass `iterators` to `example`, would that be an acceptable solution?

Comment: In your recursion `example(vector<int>(ii + 1, jj));` is passing temp `rvalue reference`, which is meaning less in your case and i wonder is it even compiling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line

```
example(vector<int>(ii + 1, jj));
```

You are creating a new vector in each call, thus not altering the one passed in to the originating call.

I think if you want to pass part of a vector and retain the original vector you can either pass indexes or iterators.

Here are 2 possible solutions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void example2(vector<int>& x, int ind = 0)
{
    if (ind < x.size()) 
    { 
        x[ind] = 1;
        example2(x, ind + 1);       
    } else 
    { 
        return;         
    }
}

void example(vector<int>::iterator start, vector<int>::iterator end)
{
    if (start == end) 
    { 
        return; 
    } else 
    { 
        *start = 1;
        example(++start, end);
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> x = { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 };
    example(x.begin(), x.end());
    //example2(x);

    for (vector<int>::iterator ii = x.begin(); ii != x.end(); ii++)
        cout << *ii << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a recursion and any call of `example(vector<int>(ii + 1, jj));` creates new vector (particularly  this `vector<int>(ii + 1, jj)` is unnamed vector created on the base of initial `x`), so it is impossible to get in `main` what you want with your code